# Is there a way to cancel all builds from queue?

Tags: teamcity

I can't find a UI way in TeamCity to clear all queued builds in bulk.

One by one is possible, but sometimes triggers/dependencies hit the fan and you end-up with tens of unwanted builds.

REST API is another way, also requires individually cancelling each build.

I expected to have "Remove All" or "Drop Queue" button

Answer (score 1):

Updated version:

```
const count = $x("//button[contains(@title,'Cancel build...')]").length;
const xxx = $x;
for( i=0 ; i<count ; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const r = xxx("//button[contains(@title,'Cancel build...')]")[0];
        r.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            const rem = xxx("//input[@id='submitRemoveQueuedBuild']")[0];
            console.log('Button', rem);
            rem.click();
        }, 1000);

    }, i * 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now an official way to do this :

1. Go to queue
2. Pause build queue
3. Select -> All X builds
4. Click on "Remove from queue..."

Answer (score 0):

Self answer :)

1. go to queue page
2. stop queue
3. copy/paste safe js code below to browser dev console (tested on chrome)

```js
const count = $x("//button[contains(@class,'removeFromQueueIcon')]").length;
const xxx = $x;
for( i=0 ; i<count ; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const r = xxx("//button[contains(@class,'removeFromQueueIcon')]")[0];
        r.onclick();
        setTimeout(() => {
            const rem = xxx("//input[@value='Remove']")[0].click();
        }, 1000);

    }, i * 2000);
}
```

4. Enter and watch your problem go away :)
5. resume queue

Answer (score 0):

You an also post a DELETE API Request to /app/rest/buildQueue

using curl or any other API tool like Postman.

Not sure if this was possible at the moment of the question asked, but it is now.